# Object relationship representation in database for nested objects

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, database, sqlite

I have classes **A, B, C and D**. **Class A, B and C have a list of D**.
eg:-

```
class A{
    int id;
    String nameA;
    List<D> listOfDs;
}

class D{
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

So that means A has a list of Ds, B has a list of Ds and C has a list of Ds

How am I supposed to represent this in a database. I am developing the client side on Android and iOS and the backend on ASP.Net.

So how do I represent this in structure on all these platforms so that they can be saved in the database?

Comment: hi Abhinav. which DB are u using?

Comment: @rakeshkashyap For Android, SQLite through DBFlow Library. For ASP .Net, SQL Server through code-first Entity Framework. For the iOS, I am using CoreData which I have sort of solved it but am not sure if it right or not.

Comment: Creating two tables for each class is the easiest solution I can see here.

Comment: @rakeshkashyap Can you please describe it in more detail? Do you mean like Table A, B, C, D and then A_D, B_D and C_D which contains all the mappings from A to D, B to D, C to D respectively?

Comment: your class looks fine. Class D is used in Class A B C. so use instance of class D in all other classes. similarly use table D's ID in other 3 tables

Comment: But then the table for class A will have values like this:-
Row.   id    name   d_id


1              1     n1        1


2              1     n1         2

I mean there will be multiple rows in Table A with each row having one foreign key to Table D

Comment: Do classes A, B and C have the same structure?

Comment: @VasilyKabunov No. The structures of A, B and C are completely different. But all of them might or might not have a list of D objects in them